# Wild Card entry in A Records does not resolve to Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, subdomain

I have hosted a site at parallels.com and have setup Wild Card Entry for that. Yet when i access Subdomain at xyz.mysite.com it is Generating Default Parallels Plesk Panel Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Up the WildCard entry for a host takes time to propagate. Hosting Server says to wait for 24-48 Hours to see if functional. After one day i had the entry working.